# Does the AC analysis on LT spice find the voltage and current due to both DC and AC sources?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, nmos

Does the AC analysis on LT spice find the voltage and current due to both DC and AC sources? Or must i do an op point analysis and a DC analysis? Im being asked to plot the voltage across Rs as a function of time. [image]

Answer (score 0):

`.AC` analysis deals with *frequency* domain. If you need to plot a quantity as a function of *time*, you need to perform a `.TRAN`, or a `.DC` analysis. `.DC` only deals with a single point in time.

But, `.AC` has its own DC operation point, which means that if you prepare your circuit for a frequency analysis, it will try to deduct an op point prior to simulation. Don't forget that `.AC` implies linearization of the circuit.